# Ps3 controler issue

Tags: ps3

We have a wireless PS3 controller and have been using it for months now. We turned it on today and it says "connect USB controller." We don't have a USB one, so what can we do to fix it?

Comment: For clarification, you turned the PS3 on and it said that?

Comment: A USB to mini-USB cable, which is used to charge them, can be used to connect it to the machine for this purpose. You may need to hit the little reset button on the back of the controller (with a paperclip, etc) to get it to realize what's going on.